# Python Pandas Splitting Strings and Storing the Remainder in New Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where observations are broken out per every two days. The values in the 'Date' column each describe a range of two days (eg 2020-02-22 to 2020-02-23).

[image: df_day.head()]

I want to spit those Date values into individual days, with a row for each day. The closest I got was by doing `newdf = df_day.set_index(df_day.columns.drop('Date',1).tolist()).Date.str.split(' to ', expand=True).stack().reset_index().loc[:, df_day.columns]`

The problem here is that the new date values are returned as NaNs. Is there a way to achieve this data broken out by individual day?

Comment: Please copy/paste the head of your data here. Don't include them as picture.

Comment: If they're all single days, why not just reindex with a normal date?  Create a new Date column, and set_index('new_date').asfreq('D')

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding, but based on the image it's a single date per row as is, just poorly labeled -- I would manipulate the index strings, and if I can't do that I would create a new date column, or new df w/ clean date and merge it.

You should be able to chop off the first 14 characters with a lambda -- leaving you with second listed date in index.
I can't reproduce this, so bear with me.

```
df.rename(index=lambda s: s[14:]) 
#should remove first 14 characters from each row label.
#leaving just '2020-02-23' in row 2. 

#If you must skip row 1, idx = df.index[1:]
#or df.iloc[1:].rename(index=lambda s: s[1:])
```

Otherwise, I would just replace it with a new datetime index.

```
didx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start ='2000-01-10', freq ='D',end='2020-02-26')
#Make sure same length as df
df.set_index(didx) 

#Or
#df['new_date'] = didx.values
#df.set_index('new_date').drop(columns=['Date'])

#Or
#df.append(didx,axis=1) #might need ignore_index=True
```